# Cakephp date validation still save and no error even though wrong input

Tags: php, validation, date, cakephp

I'm using cakephp validation for a field called birthdate.

my model is

```
'birthdate' => array(
    'rule'       => 'date',
    'message'    => 'Enter a valid date',
    'allowEmpty' => true    
),
```

my question is how come it's still save correctly even though it's invalid input. e.g:

March 27, 1988
so, if I put it like this, and the array result like this

```
//this will work
'birthdate' => array(
    'month' => '3#',
    'day' => '27',
    'year' => '1988'
)

//this will NOT work
'birthdate' => array(
    'month' => '#3',
    'day' => '27',
    'year' => '1988'
)
```

why the first one still validate it (still save correctly. e.g: the end result still march 27, 1988)? but I would like to have consistency. is there anyway to report an error?

Comment: We need some more info. Please post the form/inputs. Also, please give an example of what should and should not pass validation.  Your wording of "this will work" and "will not work" aren't very helpful. Do you mean work as in it saves (which may or may not be desired), or work as in the validation is as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Complex data type deconstruction

Dates are being passed as arrays, so they need to be formatted to a string first. In case the column in the database is of type `date*`, the value is being formatted automatically so that it fits the proper column type format.

Ultimately this is done in `Model::deconstruct()` (it ends up there when calling `Model::set()`, which normally happens *before* validation), where the individual values are being passed through `sprintf()`:

```
$date[$index] = sprintf('%02d', $date[$index]);
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.5/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1336**

## Integer casting

And that's the answer to your first question, it's that formatting directive that is responsible for this behavior, it casts the individual date values to integers, where `3#` evaluates to a number, while `#3` fails (and ends up as `00`), that's how string conversion in PHP works.

See **http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion**

## Use custom validation/formatting

So in order to be able to trigger an error on such input you'll either have to use a [**custom validation rule**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules), which would require to for example pass the data using a different fieldname so that it's not being formatted in `Model::set()`, or use custom formatting (for example by overwriting `Model::set()` or `Model::deconstruct()`) to flatten the complex value in a way that the individual values are not being casted.